# how to prove these sums?

Tags: measure-theory

let $(X,\mathcal{\Sigma},\mu)$ be a measure space

let $f, g $ be simple measurable functions that maps from $X$ onto $\overline {\mathbb{R}}$ such that $ f \leq g$

meaning :
$$f = \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i \mathbf{1}_{E_i} $$ 
$$g = \sum_{k=1}^{m}d_k \mathbf{1}_{F_k} $$ 
$$ E_i \cap F_k \neq \emptyset \implies c_i \leq d_k  $$

both $ E_i$ & $F_k$ are elements of the $\sigma$-algebra and form a partition of $X$

$\mathbf{1}$ represents the indicator function

I'm having a hard time trying to prove these two sums which are needed to prove a certain lemma :

$$g = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{m}d_k \mathbf{1}_{E_i \cap F_k } $$ 
$$f = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{m} c_i \mathbf{1}_{E_i \cap F_k } $$

any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, notice that $\mathbf{1}_{E_i\cap F_k}=\mathbf{1}_{E_i}\mathbf{1}_{F_k}$, and since $E_i$ form a partition, we have $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{1}_{E_i}=1$. Thus
$$g=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{1}_{E_i}g=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{1}_{E_i}\sum_{k=1}^{m}d_k\mathbf{1}_{F_k} =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{m}d_k\mathbf{1}_{E_i\cap F_k}$$
The same goes for $f$.